# How do I sweeten a mulled or spiced wine that is too tart?

Tags: wine

I prepared a spiced wine according to a [recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/hot-spiced-christmas-wine/) last night using Cabernet with a mix of Pinot Grigio and Rum. I suspect the Cabernet caused it to come out on the tart side after reading this [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20229/does-it-matter-what-type-of-wine-is-used-to-make-mulled-wine).

The recipe called for brown sugar, which I used, but it doesn't seem sweet enough. Should I add more brown sugar or is there a better way to sweeten the wine and temper the tartness?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More sugar would seem to be the logical choice...

Comment: That's what I was thinking... I was worried that more sugar might produce some sort of a negative chemical reaction with the cooked wine, but if not, that sounds like the obvious option.

Comment: Try sweetening a small portion, and see what happens.

Comment: Lol, yeah oddly enough I didn't think to do that. I will try that first and let you guys know what happens. I want to serve it tonight at a dinner, so we'll see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used both sugar and orange juice to sweeten mulled wine in the past, but obviously orange juice would change the flavour significantly. Add more sugar slowly, tasting as you go.

Comment: So I prepped it the night before my dinner cause I wasn't going to have much time to prepare the night of. I took people's advice and added more brown sugar slowly and cooked it for another 30 mins and it came out delicious! Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

In a pinch, when cold thirsty guests are waiting, port sweetens things up and adds a deep rich flavor. Imbibers certainly will get warmed up fast! Just a few whiffs might be all they need.

Comment: I love that idea. If I hadn't've already added Rum to the mix, this would've been perfect!

Comment: I think I once added cherry brandy, rum and a bit of whisky at different points in a batch of mulled wine's life. Every time the slow cooker started looking emptyish I'd chuck in some more wine, OJ and spirits in. The bottom of the last batch sort of seeded the flavour quite fast, I left the spices in and didn't really need to add more spices.